# Qt - How to change background from editable QComboBox?

Tags: qt, stylesheet

I'm facing this problem when styling an editable QComboBox:
[image]

I'm unable to change the color of the grey box inside the QComboBox...
Any idea how to change it just with a stylesheet?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
QComboBox:editable {
    background: white;
}
```

? I did not test it, but the [reference](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.6/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qcombobox) seems good to me.

---

**Edit**

As of using Qt version 5.6.2 the provided change works as desired. No differently colored box inside the currently edited QComboBox.

Comment: Hi maxik, if I do that only the light blue changes, but not the greyed box... that's because I think it's kind of an "inherited QLineEdit"...

Comment: @dolphinboy If so, then I would recommend providing your current style sheet or I may not help you further. Additionally, provide the version of Qt you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This shoud work

```
YourCombobox->findChild<QLineEdit*>()->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit {background: green;}");
```

Previous line get the reference to the QLineEdit which is part of the QComboBox widget and applies the style sheet to it, not to the combobox.

I don't know if this could also work, if you want to try it and give a feedback..

```
YourCombobox->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit {background: green;}");
```

Comment: Thank Andre, the problem is that I cannot change code, I'm only able to edit the stylesheet (.qss file)...

Comment: Oh sorry I've missed that..In this case I can't help you and I don't know if it's possible to change QLineEdit background just modifying stylesheet